# Maximal Interval of existence for the Given Initial value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The given initial value problem is

> $$ y{\prime}(t)=f(y(t))\;\;,\;\;y(0)=a \in\mathbb{R}\\where\;\; f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$$

Then

> $\text{The maximal interval of existence for the above problem is $\mathbb{R}$ when $f$ is bounded and} $ $\text{continuously differentiable}$

i have no idea how to proceed .
Please help

Thankyou.

Comment: What do you know about the cases where the maximal interval is finite in one direction?

Comment: Never heard about this  before.Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: The maximal solution leaves every compact set contained in the domain of the ODE. If the interval is $(a,b)$ with $b$ finite, what does this say about boxes $[b-1,b+1]\times [-N,N]$, which are compact and contained in the domain?

Comment: i am not getting  it, can you please solve This.

Comment: If the solution enters such a box on the left side, which side of the box can it leave?

Comment: can leave box form top ,bottom or from right.

Comment: How can it leave at the right if the domain of the solution ends at $b$, that is, does not reach $b+1$? Next consider that the situation remains the same if you increase $N$ arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is bounded, $|f(y)| \le M$ for all $y\in\Bbb R$, then you get for the solution if the IVP
$$
|y(t)-a|\le M\,|t|
$$
for all $t$ in the domain of the maximal solution.

As the maximal solution $y$ can not reach infinity at finite times, it is defined on the whole of $\Bbb R$.